# Android build suddenly taking 10-15 minutes

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

I upgraded my gradle build tool to com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4.

Since then my builds are taking 10-15 instead of seconds.

Also, I have updated my gradle itself.
This is my gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

I am totally stuck.
I have performed a clean and an invalidate cache to no avail.

One of the places it seems to get stuck is on

```
kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
```

The relevant sections of my project level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.0"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:6.0.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"
    }
}
```

Build analyser (the two biggest)

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Comment: Why not version `7.2`? A Gradle question without any `build.gradle` is rather a complaint.

Comment: @MartinZeitler My bad - updated

Answer (score 0):

If you clean and invalidate caches, then gradle needs to rebuild those to complete the build.
Once you have completed the build once, without making any further code changes, rebuild again.

When you rebuild this time, look at the list of tasks that were carried out. They should mostly report `UP-TO-DATE`. Some may say `NO-SOURCE`. Any that don't are tasks that needed to run.

This build should inevitably be quicker than the last.

[image]

You can then use either a [gradle build scan](https://blog.gradle.org/introducing-build-scans) or Android Studio build analyzer and see further details of what task needed to re-run.

Using build analyzer you can see some reasoning as to why the task needed to run.
[image]

I've seen lots of different reasons for tasks needing to run. Obviously if some source code changes, then it needs to recompile, but even things like changing the target device in Android Studio can be enough to trigger rebuilding.

Hope this helps you to understand what gradle is doing.
Based on the details you have given in the question, there is not enough to determine the actual reason though.

Comment: I am building at the moment. Will post the output when it has finished. But at the moment it is stuck on kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin

Comment: I have added two pics with details of the worst two culprits.

Comment: So you can see that on those images, the build analyzer is telling you that StringFunctions.kt has changed. Therefore the task needs to re-run. If you keep changing that file, it'll keep needing to re-run.

Comment: But still, 10-15 minutes is a long time.

Comment: Yes. Especially if you have to build lots of times per day, and each build takes that long. There are many resources on how to improve build times for android apps. But there is no 1 overall solution because each project has different dependencies and architecture, so the way forward has to be to understand what makes it take that long.

Comment: I just did another build immediately- without making any changes. Still took the same time. The only reason it gives is "Input property 'classpath' file E:\AndroidStudioProjects\android-clients\WeFiUtil\app\build\intermediates\compile_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar has changed"

Comment: As I mentioned previously, there is not enough detail in the question for me to determine the actual reason. But a quick google on `"Input property 'classpath' has changed` came up with this : https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-rebuilds-unchanged-common-subprojects/21206

Answer (score 0):

I'm stuck in downloading kotlin-embedded compiler for so long, I fix it
by adding

```
gradlePluginPortal under Project level build.gradle file under buildscript->repositories
```

[image: project level build.gradle]